# Expanding a ket in the position basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

My textbook says that to find the ket $|ψ\rangle$ in the same position basis as the ket $|ø\rangle$ we do the following: $$|ψ\rangle=\int dø|ø\rangle \langle ø|ψ\rangle$$ Firstly can $|ø\rangle$ be any ket? i.e. this expression just puts $|ψ\rangle$ in the same basis as $|ø\rangle$ regardless of the components of $|ø\rangle$?

Secondly my textbook goes on to say to place $|ψ\rangle$ in the position basis we do the following:  $$|ψ\rangle=\int d^3r\ |\mathbf{r}\rangle\langle \mathbf{r}|ψ\rangle$$
Why have we suddenly gained a cubed sign?

Are we taking the integral over nothing? i.e. are the integrals we are doing simply $\int dø$ and $\int d^3r$?

(I am new to this sort of physics/maths and am self teaching so please can you keep the explanations relativity simple) thanks

Comment: That is because the Hilbert space you are considering is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, the space of square-integral functions of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I've replaced $r$ by $\mathbf{r}$ to emphasise this in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, the first equation you gave is only correct, if the $|ø\rangle$ form a **basis**. It has nothing to do with "in which basis they are".

The easiest way to understand this is probably with a 3D vector-analogy. So if $b_i$, $i=1\dots3$ form a basis, for any vector $v$ it is legitimate to write $$v=\sum_{i=1}^3 b_i (b_i\cdot v)$$
There, the $b_i\cdot v$ are the components of $v$ in the representation of the $b_i$.

It is the very same for bras and kets. It is "just" not 3d but has infinite dimension, so if we have a basis of infinite $|ø\rangle$, $ø\in \mathbb{R}$ or $|r\rangle$, $r\in \mathbb{R}^3$, denote the scalar product ($a\cdot b$) using dirac notatiton ($\langle a|b\rangle$), and write integrals instead of sums we get te formulas given by you (mathematically this is non trivial). Therefor the $\langle r|\psi\rangle$ are the components in the position basis.

Comment: Would $<r|=(i,j,k)$ ?

Comment: $\langle r|$ is a function (it is element of the dual space) acting on a vector/ket giving a scalar. So yes, in this simplified picture you are correct.

Comment: Is it the fact that $<r|$ is 3 dimensional that we have the cubed? thanks

Comment: If you have three dimensional space, you need all those three dimensions to form a **complete** basis. So yes, that is the reason.

Comment: I know this is a simple question but lets say $<A|$ is a basis consisting of $(a_1,a_1,...,a_n)$ then any vector $|V>$ can be written as $|V>=v_ia_i=<A|V>$ where $a_i$ themsevles are vectors??

Comment: also do we only need to integrate when $<A|$ has an infinte amount of components.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part of your question,they have just inserted a complete set of basis because $|\phi>$ is a basis in some infinite dimensional Hilbert space (in your case), therefore sum (integral) of all such bases is identity on the Hilbert space. Note that in second part

$\langle r|\phi\rangle$=$\phi(r)$.